# Banach Alaoglu different proofs

Tags: functional-analysis, alternative-proof

While trying to prove Banach-Alaoglu theorem I noticed the differrent equivalent definitions of compactness. When I tried to find a proof of Banach-Alaoglu I found a proof in Pedersen Analysis Now and it uses nets.

Is there a known proof of Banach-Alaoglu for each of [the different equivalent definitions of compactness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space#Equivalent_definitions)?

Comment: Do you mean Banach-Alaoglu for sequentially compactness i.e If $X^*$ is a seperable Banach space then every bounded sequence $(x_n^*)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset X^*$ has a weakly* converging subsequnce? Or do you mean the general Banach-Alaoglu which says that the unit ball in $X^*$ is weakly* compact?

Comment: @Thorben I mean the general case.

Comment: In Rudin, the proof is given by identifying the space with a product space of $R$ and make the compactness follow from Tychonoff's theorem. The proof is in effect equivalent to Pederson's, albeit actually much longer and I am not entirely sure whether it is a simplification of the net argument (I personally do not think so)